# How to prevent extra re-render of child components of a function component react?

Tags: reactjs

I have created a simple Reactjs application. It uses two components a `CounterButton` and a `CounterDisplay`. Both are function components.

Both these components are used in another function component `FunctionComponent` which maintains the state of counter. The problem is that whenever I click on the `CounterButton` it renders the button again.

In contrast I created another component, `ClassComponent` which is a class component equivalent to `FunctionComponent`, and it does not re-render the button on each click.

I understand that the extra render is because I'm using arrow function clickHandler in `FunctionComponent`, but don't know how to fix this.

```js
import React from 'react';

const CounterButton = React.memo((props) => {
  console.log(`${props.name} Counter Button Rendered`);
  return (<>
    <button onClick={props.onClick}>{props.name}: Click</button>
    </>)
});
const CounterDisplay = React.memo((props) => {
  console.log('Counter Display Rendered');
  return (<>
    <div>{props.name} : {props.counter}</div>
    </>)
});

function FunctionComponent() {
  const [counter, setCounter] = React.useState(0);

  var clickHandler = () => {
    console.log(">>> FunctionComponent: button clicked <<< ")
    setCounter(counter + 1);
  };
  console.log('---FunctionComponent render---')
  return <>
    <CounterButton name="FunctionComponent" onClick={clickHandler} />
    <CounterDisplay name="FunctionComponent" counter = {counter} />
  </>
}

class ClassComponent extends React.Component {
  state = {
    counter: 0
  };

  clickHandler = () => {
    console.log(">>> ClassComponent: button clicked <<< ")
    this.setState(prev => ({counter: prev.counter + 1}));
  };
  render() {   
    console.log('---ClassComponent render---')
    return <>
      <CounterButton name="ClassComponent" onClick={this.clickHandler} />
      <CounterDisplay name= "ClassComponent" counter = {this.state.counter} />
    </>
  }
}

function App() {
  return <>
    <FunctionComponent/>
    <ClassComponent/>
  </>
}
export default App;
```

Application starts and I see all components rendered once

```
---FunctionComponent render---
FunctionComponent Counter Button Rendered
Counter Display Rendered
---ClassComponent render---
ClassComponent Counter Button Rendered
Counter Display Rendered
```

When I click on the `FunctionComponent`'s `CounterButton` react re-renders the button again.

```
>>> FunctionComponent: button clicked <<< 
---FunctionComponent render---
FunctionComponent Counter Button Rendered
Counter Display Rendered
```

When I click on the `ClassComponent`'s `CounterButton` react does not re-render the button again.

```
>>> ClassComponent: button clicked <<< 
---ClassComponent render---
Counter Display Rendered
```

I tried using `useCallBack` for `clickHandler`, but it didn't change anything.

```
  var clickHandler = useCallback(() => {
    console.log(">>> FunctionComponent: button clicked <<< ")
    setCounter(counter + 1);
  },[counter]);
```

How to achieve the same behavior in `FunctionComponent` i.e. not re-render button on each click?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I tried using useCallBack for clickHandler, but it didn't change anything.
>
> ```
>  var clickHandler = useCallback(() => {
>    console.log(">>> FunctionComponent: button clicked <<< ")
>    setCounter(counter + 1);
>  },[counter]);
> ```

The reason it didn't change anything is that you're creating a new click handler every time `counter` changes. Change your code to use the function version of setState, and remove counter from the dependency array:

```
const clickHandler = useCallback(() => {
  setCounter(prev => prev + 1);
}, []);
```